# Why am I unable to access the data property on this object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on my first React project and in this project I'm storing images on MongoDB. (Not best practice, I know, but regardless...)

My mongoDB object has a number of properties, including one property called "coverImage" which is an object that holds two properties: type & data, which looks like this: {Type: buffer, data: Array(6450).

I'm having trouble accessing the data property. When logging to the console the value of the data property within axios, the buffer is logged to the console without issue.

Meanwhile, when attempting to access this value, which was stored in state, I receive a TypeError: "Cannot read property data of undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Please see my code below:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    // import BookCover from "../utilities/BookCover";

    class BookPage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          book: ""
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:3000/books/" + this.props.match.params.id)
          .then(res => {
            console.log("first object", res.data.coverImage); // Returns fist object, {type: Buffer, data: Array(6450)}
            console.log("buffer", res.data.coverImage.data); // Returns buffer (6450) [255, 216 ...]
            this.setState({
              book: res.data
            });
          });
      }

      bookDetails() {
        console.log("second object", this.state.book.coverImage); // Returns second object, {type: Buffer, data: Array(6450)}
        // console.log(this.state.book.coverImage.data); // Returns TypeError: "Cannot read property data of undefined"
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.book.title}</h1>
            <p>Author: TBD</p>
            <p>Publish Date: {this.state.book.publishDate} </p>
            <p>Need to Read: {String(this.state.book.unread)} </p>
            <p>Page Count: {this.state.book.pageCount} </p>
            <p>Description: {this.state.book.description} </p>
          </div>
        );
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{this.bookDetails()}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default BookPage;
```

Comment: You need to convert it to json try `res.json()`

Comment: Did you try to console the "type" 
console.log(this.state.book.coverImage.type)?

Comment: just put some null checks since the async call is not yet complete and book is not yet available `if(book.coverImage) return existing logic else return loading`

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Please correct me if I'm wrong, but axios is getting all of the data in JSON format. This is why the title, publishDate, unread, pageCount and description values were able to be rendered to the page. In addition, my first log within bookDetails (this.state.book.coverImage) was successful in displaying the object.

Comment: @AjayGhosh yes, I've tried "type" for all of the four console logs above and it leads to the exact same result. Edit: for clarification, I mean that the successful attempts (first two in axios and first one within bookDetails are successful while the last one returns an error)

Comment: Not sure why `this.state.book.coverImage` works initially, but your state is initially just an empty string. So when the component first mounts, you can access `this.state.book`, which will be `""`. And you can access `this.state.book.X`, which will be undefined. But if try to go any deeper, you'll get the error you're getting, cos you're trying to access properties of undefined. In your render, try `<div>{this.state.book && this.bookDetails()}</div>` and see if that fixes it. If so, you'll have to deal with asynchronicity of data loading with loading spinner or message.

Comment: Oh and if `this.state.book` is meant to be an object once data has loaded, set it to `null` initially in constructor. Makes no sense to set it to an empty string.

Comment: @Jayce444 that worked! Yes, I noticed that my first console.log in bookDetails was being called twice. First it was undefined but on the second time it stopped short at the coverImage object. I knew that this was normal behavior because each time setState is called, the page re-renders. Anyway, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jayce444 Will do! I agree, setting it to empty string doesn't make sense. I kept switching between empty string/object/array to see if that had any impact. Obviously not. Thanks again